# How to convert the values of a variable to alphabetic names

Tags: stata

I have a variable `gender` and it has two values 0 and 1. I want to convert these values to male and female respectively

I have tried `tostring` and `decode`, but they are unable to do the task.

Answer (score 1):

This is really basic stuff and explained in any elementary introduction to Stata (which is, I guess, why the question is being downvoted for lack of research).

```
label def gender 0 male 1 female 
label val gender gender
```

However, `gender` is a poor name for such a variable. A good convention is to name any indicator variable with values (0, 1) for the category coded 1. So

```
rename gender female
```

Then summaries have the right interpretation: for example the mean of `female` is indeed the proportion who are female.

`tostring` and `decode` indeed have no role to play here.